# Как удалить комментарий на этом сайте?

Tags: поддержка, удаление-комментариев

Я хочу удалить комментарий. Как это сделать?

Comment: Возле каждого комментария есть кнопочка удаления

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzWSA.png

Comment: @gil9red новые пользователи не могут писать на Мету вроде бы

Comment: @andreymal, ответы - в ответы.

Answer (score 2):

Самостоятельно можно удалять только собственные комментарии. Для удаления комментария нужно выбрать ссылку "Удалить", которая появляется при наведении курсора на комментарий.

> [image: Удаление комментария]

На устройствах с тач-скрином ссылка "Удалить" отображается всегда.